# how can i use a logical function to represent continuous parameters?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to use an "implication" function that take two parameters f(A,B)= A -> B. In boolean algebra this kind of functions (eg. conjunction , disjunction ...) are used with only boolean parameters (true or false , 1 or 0).Imagine that these parameters take continuous values (between 0 and 1) and that the result function (A,B) will take also values between 0 and 1 instead of true or false.
for example :

---

when A increases(is near 1) and B increases(is near 1) f(A,B) increases(near 1)

when A increases and B decreases f(A,B) decreases

when A decreases and B increases f(A,B) increases

when A decreases and B decreases f(A,B) increases

---

How can i parse the implication function into a mathematical function that handle my continues values ?

Comment: According to your description, `f(A,B)` only increases when B increases and only decreases when B decreases.  SO `f(A,B) = B` is the simplest continuous relation that satisfies these requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The problem can be solved using the Fuzzy logic, which is a form of many-valued logic in which the truth values of variables may be any real number between 0 and 1. By contrast, in Boolean logic, the truth values of variables may only be 0 or 1. Fuzzy logic has been extended to handle the concept of partial truth, where the truth value may range between completely true and completely false. So may boolean implication function would be transformed to a fuzzy implication function, see [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4374117) for more details.